# How to integrate dynamical share button in laravel 4.1?

Tags: facebook, laravel, laravel-4

So i have build basic CMS and website. Next i want to integrate Facebook and Twitter share buttons, but i'm stuck. Can anyone explain me how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use composer packages...there are several...

You can look [Share links with Laravel 4](https://github.com/thujohn/share-l4)

The documentation is very easy to follow...

If you ever need some packages, you can always search 
[packagist](https://packagist.org/)

If you want laravel specific packages there is also
[packalyst](http://packalyst.com/)

a snippet... I am using in my project

```
<a href="{{ Share::load(Request::url() , $news->title)->facebook() }} >Facebook</a>"
```

Comment: This one is all i need, but i can't figure out how to fetch url. Here is my controller and view, can you take an eye on my code?

http://help.laravel.io/08d2c63b0705d81479a93f0d48bcf36495630c39

Comment: please check my application snippet... http://help.laravel.io/79e087fa866d4ca3d20d528a79981f5e62fed7a7    | as for url generation, Request::url() should automatically generate your current single post url.... and you are using post->id, which should be post->title as it will show as title in social network. Also check the share's source code/load method... https://github.com/thujohn/share-l4/blob/master/src/Thujohn/Share/Share.php

Comment: i think i figure it out, only problem is that i run server local, so it want generate valid link. When i deploy app, everything should work, i think :) Thnx